# can I get the month from the time stamp if it is possible how canI do that?

Tags: php, timestamp

When a image is uploaded to the site I want to display the month which it was uploaded under the picture. I have a time-stamp field in the database.

Can I get the month from the time stamp if it is possible how can I do that?

I tried to do it using this code

```
<?php $query="SELECT * FROM magimgdes ORDER BY id DESC, time DESC " ;

  $result=mysql_query($query) OR DIE(mysql_error());
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $value1=$row['image'];
      $value3=$row['time'];
     ?>
  <img src="admin/upload/hompageimage/<?php echo $value1; ?>" width="180" height="195" alt="magimage" />

 <?php echo $value3;} ?></div>
```

The "time" field is the timestamp field in database.

I just want to echo only the month.

Comment: A "time-stamp" field in the database is ambiguous. What is the column type? Or are you referring to a UNIX timestamp?

Comment: What does print `$row['time']` look like ???

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Comment: Please add more info about why the answers don't solve your question or mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** , you can  get by [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
$weekday = date('N', $timestamp); 
$month = date('m', $timestamp);   
$day = date('d', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the date function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to convert the MySql datetime format to UNIX timestamp, to do that you can use `strtotime` function. Then you can use many functions to deal in the extraction of the month, for example `getdate` function.

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row['time']); // Convert to unix time.
$info = getdate($timestamp); // Get the fields of a date (in an array).
$month = $info['mon']; // This is the element that contains the month.
echo $month; // This will print a number from 1 to 12.
```